# Snippets in VS Code that use text found in the file with a regular expression

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a React Native snippet that is `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)($0)` where the cursor appears in the final parens so I can enter the class name.

Assuming I'm always using this snippet in a file that has a class defined in it (`class ClassName extends Component {`), is there a way to write the snippet so that it *automatically* fills in the current ClassName? Using regexp or something, to start.

For example, given this code at the beginning of the file:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class MyClass extends Component {
  ...
  ...
```

When I type, inside that file, my snippet shortcut for what is currently `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)($0)` (which gives me that code with the cursor where the `$0` is) I want it to instantly get this:

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyClass)
```

Perhaps it's something like this:

````js
"body": "export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)({/class (\w+) extends/})"```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a regular expression into a snippet except to transform one of the built-in variables.  If `MyClass` was already on the clipboard you could just use `$CLIPBOARD` in your snippet:

```
"body": "export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)($CLIPBOARD)"
```

---

Update: new answer

Using an extension that I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), this is now pretty easy.  It allows you to get the entire text and **do a match in the `replace`** to get the info you need from any part of the file - as long as you can make a regex for it.

Put this keybinding in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+e",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
 
    //  no find necessary, will insert returned value at cursor(s)    
    
    "replace": [ 
      "$${",
      
        "const fullText = `${getDocumentText}`;",
        
        "let foundClass = '';",  // set to empty string in case of no match in text  
        "const match = fullText.match(/class ([^\\s]+) extends/);",
        "if (match?.length) foundClass = match[1];",  // get capture group 1
        
        "return `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(${foundClass})`;",
        
      "}$$"
    ],
    
    "postCommands": "cancelSelection"
  },
}
```

[image: use a regex match in a find and replace]

Comment: Thank you! Sounds comprehensive, but it's maybe easier to just type in the class name after I activate the snippet. Amazing work!

Comment: Yes, this is a proof-of-concept.  You can grab text from anywhere in the file (maybe workspace too although I didn't try to do that), go back to where you were and use that text in a snippet.  That is pretty powerful and fast.  Don't forget to accept and/or upvote the answer if you found it helpful.